# How to split a String my Empty lines in java

Tags: java

can anyone help me how to split string by empty lines?
for example i have following string

```
abc def ghk
122 saf fsaf

sfa fasf

afsf
```

i want to split above string by empty lines and output should be as follows

```
string[0] = "abc def ghk
    122 saf fsaf"
String[1]="sfa fasf"
String[2]="afsf"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You can split the string on a newline that has only whitespace until the next newline:

```
String input = "abc def ghk\n122 saf fsaf\n\nsfa fasf afsf";
String[] split = input.split("\n\\s*\n");
System.out.println(split[0]);
```